# Проверка состояния бота discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Хочу сделать бота который будет отслеживать состояние других ботов. Как можно сделать проверку состояния другого бота или пользователя (Онлайн он или же оффлайн)?

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень легко и просто, достаточно сделать проверку на состояние пользователя и вывести его статус.

```js
let mem = message.guild.members.get(message.author.id) // cюда можно вставить id пользователя
if (mem.presence.status == 'online') status = 'В сети' // если такой статус то выводим "В сети"
message.channel.send(status) // сам вывод сообщения
```